# Pix from iPhone 6 show up on iCloud, but not on iMac's new Photos app

Tags: photos

Using latest operating systems on both iPhone and iMac. The photos taken from iPhone are not showing up on my iMac's Photos app.  I have "My Photo Stream" turned on in Photos' iCloud preferences. However, they used to show up within seconds on Aperture on iMac.

Comment: how long ago did you turn on the stream ?

Comment: It took me 15 minutes to up load 9 pics from iP6 to Photos app through iCloud ...seems kinda slow, It took me 6 days to upload 26k pics to iCloud, where I was able to see them on my iP6, I have a 35 down and 5 up through Charter I used a combo of wifi and Ethernet during that time.